# what is difference between before-save-hook and write-file-functions

Tags: emacs, elisp

I read the manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Buffers.html#Saving-Buffers, but still not quite understand what is the difference between the two. It seems to me they both work as a hook to run whatever function you set before saving the buffer to the visited file. could anyone explain with examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write-*-functions` provide a strict superset of what `before-save-hook` can do.  More specifically, `write-*-functions` can *replace* the normal saving mechanism with another one.  This means that a function added to `write-*-functions` might end up unused because some earlier function has already saved the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`write-file-functions` *can* be used to simply do arbitrary things before saving the file, but its stated purpose is to allow some non-default function to actually do the work of *saving* the file (or perhaps to manipulate the content for the purposes more directly related to the saving mechanism itself).

If modifying the mechanism for saving a file is not what you wish to do, I strongly suspect you should be using `before-save-hook`.

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Saving Buffers` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say that `before-save-hook` is here to modify the content. While `write-*-functions` are in charge of coding systems (compress the file content for instance or following any other file format) and the backup files.

Moreover `write-*-functions` may be buffer local while it does not seem to be the case for `before-save-hook`. But then I am not sure to know what it implies.

Comment: so they are basically exchangeable?

Comment: I would say no. What is your goal?

Comment: you explanation seems indicate they are conventionally used in different scenario rather than they have mechanistic difference. I use it for `delete-trailing-whitespace` to delete unneccessary whitespaces, but I am just interested in their general functionality